# Expected value of Log Gamma function transformed Poisson random variable

Tags: poisson-distribution, expected-value

This question came up during my research. In detail, let $X$ be Poisson distribution, i.e. $X\sim Pois(\lambda)$. I am interested in the expected value

$$ \mathbb{E}\left[\log\left(\frac{\Gamma(X+c)}{\Gamma(X+d)}\right)\right],\qquad (1)$$

where $c,d>0$.

My idea to calculate the expected value was to calculate first the expected value $\mathbb{E}\left[\log\left(\Gamma(X+c)\right)\right]$ based on some series expansion of the log Gamma function. However, this resulted in being stuck at the expected value of $\mathbb{E}\left[\log\left(X+c\right)\right]$.

Does anybody have some advice on this?

Edit based on comments below:

- $c$ and $d$ can but do not have to be integers.
- The Gamma function is defined by $\Gamma(z) = \int_0^\infty x^{z-1} e^{-x}\,dx$.
- Delta method: It was suggested to consider the Delta method. I think it does not really apply here as I do not have a sequence of random variables. That being said, I compared (1) with $ \log\left(\frac{\Gamma(\lambda+c)}{\Gamma(\lambda+d)}\right)$ and the difference is generally too big to consider this approximation. Here is the R code:

  ```
  lambda <- 3
  c <- 1.5
  d <- 3.2
  x <- seq(0, 2000)
  sum((lgamma(x + c) - lgamma(x + d)) * dpois(x = x, lambda = lambda))
  lgamma(lambda + c) - lgamma(lambda + d)
  ```

Comment: Can you define $\Gamma$ also? I understand it is Gamma function, but just for the completeness of the question.

Comment: Delta method ... ?? Don't know if that will be good enough for your application.

Comment: $c$ and $d$ wouldn't, by great good fortune, happen to be integers, would they?

Comment: Thank you, everybody. I edited the original question to address your comments.

Comment: I'm still wondering for a non-Taylor answer even if $c$ and $d$ were integers.